# Showing/hiding elements of an extension interface in Inkscape

Tags: python, user-interface, inkscape

I am creating an extension in Inkscape, and I was wondering whether there was a way to show/hide (or at least disable) certain elements of the interface.

For instance, say in my .inx file I define an `optiongroup` with several options, which rely on different parameters. I would like the corresponding edit boxes for the parameters to appear/disappear depending on the selection in the `optiongroup`.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: What's with the downvote? This is a perfectly on topic programming question.  In any case, if you downvote you should explain why you did it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible, without editing this file: `prefdialog.cpp`

- http://fossies.org/dox/inkscape-0.48.5/prefdialog_8cpp_source.html

You could try your luck at forking a version of it?